# $G$-harmonic polynomials, dimension of $\text{Harm}(\mathbb{R}^n, S_n)$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, polynomials, harmonic-analysis, symmetric-groups, harmonic-functions

> **Definition.** Let $\text{Harm}(\mathbb{R}^n, G)$ be the space of $G$-harmonic polynomials on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is, what is the dimension of $\text{Harm}(\mathbb{R}^n, S_n)$?

Comment: It is equal to $n!$. See, for example, Talk 6 in Math Talks for Undergraduates by Serge Lang.